# Determining partially Overlapped features from two linear feature classes

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, overlapping-features

I have been trying to find object ids of features that overlap partially.
Input taken is two linear feature classes , I have tried IRelationalOperator Overlaps methords , but it seems that it only provides those features that overlaps completely.

Is there any way round to get those features which overlap partially

The other way I tried was through esriSpatialRelationOverlap methord but it seems to produce error, which I have posted in following forum link .

http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/87164-AutomationException-0x80004005-error-while-quering-overlapped-features?p=308026#post308026

How do I resolve this issue?

---

Got the answer by using "esriSpatialRelOverlaps"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing the issue but intersect will give you the overlap of features. I'm not familiar with arcobjects, but arcpy.Intersect_analysis() is easy access for the Python shell provided with arcgis.
Intersect will return all attributes of all intersecting polygons (including obj ids).

By "linear", if you mean polylines, intersect will return two overlapping features. Otherwise, a buffer could be applied to represent the true width of the feature represented by the polyline.

Alternatively, you could convert the feature classes to raster and find their intersection with an overlay or raster math.